# WordPress custom API with WooCommerce Authentication

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I have created custom API in WordPress and I am getting WooCommerce Subscription data in this API and its working fine as per my requirements.

Howerver, now I want to add basic authentication in this API which can check consumer key and secret like other WooCommerce API endpoints.

This is my sample API looks like in which I want to check basic authentication.

```
// Action to execute Rest API routes
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

    // Getting Product data based on subscription id
    register_rest_route('getproductdata', '/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getProductData',
    ));
});


function getProductData($request) {
    // I WANT TO CHECK BASIC AUTHENTICATION HERE BEFORE EXECUTING BELOW CODE 


    die('inside my api');
}
```

I have checked this https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355041/how-to-authenticate-custom-api-endpoint-in-woocommerce this urls but I have not found yet proper method or filter or tutorial yet to accomplish my requirements.

Can someone at-least guide me how can I add authentication here .. any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys.. Eventually I made authentication in my custom endpoint APIs using [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/).

Thanks everyone for help , support and guidance.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can use the `permission_callback` key:

```
// Action to execute Rest API routes
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

    // Getting Product data based on subscription id
    register_rest_route('getproductdata', '/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'getProductData',
        'permission_callback' => 'restCheckUser'
    ));
});


function getProductData($request) {
    // I WANT TO CHECK BASIC AUTHENTICATION HERE BEFORE EXECUTING BELOW CODE


    die('inside my api');
}

function restCheckUser(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    if ('get_token_from_database' === $request->get_param('token')) {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Full Documentation is here - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Thank you so so much for this answer .. can you just tell me do i need to put logic something like authentication here ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave The `perrmission_callback` to execute before `callback`

Comment: Yea .. I know that .. but I want something like this `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v1/orders` if you directly run this woocomerce wordpress api .. then it wont be executed .. it will ask us to enter authorization inputs like consumer key and secret .. i want this feature in my custom api this one ..

Comment: so i use postman and enter authorization .. oauth1 to select then only i can get orders data .. so i want to achieve this  authorization in `permission_callback` which you suggested .. so my question is, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: I know something like this `'permission_callback' => function() {  return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ); },` but i dont want to check this .. instead i want authorization to check..

Comment: something like sending headers in my custom API you know ..

Comment: thanks for updating your answer .. i have added something like this `print_r($request->get_param('oauth_consumer_key'));` in `restCheckUser` function and I am getting consumer key .. which i have added from backend woocommerce settings .. but my question is, how can i validate whether its entered valid or not .. ?

Comment: Just like other woocommerce apis, if its valid then only my api shoud continue executing further data .. i just can not check if condition with static value ..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave you should get your token from `database`

Comment: I have added my answer / solution.. Thanks for support.

Comment: hou you can validate from database, in what table are storage this